# Problemas com "strcpy" travando o programa

Tags: c, string, arquivo

Estou resolvendo um exercício onde tenho de preencher um vetor do tipo `struct`, e um dos valores é `char`, para isso fiz um `while` e estava utilizando uma atribuição simples com "=" mas não estava dando certo, então fiz com `strcpy` mas toda vez que rodo o programa ele não abre e trava.

Aqui está o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct aluno{
    char* name;
    float nota1, nota2, media;  
}aluno;

void resize (FILE *arq);
void fill (aluno *std, FILE * arq);
void menu (aluno* std, FILE *arq);
void consulta (aluno* std, FILE *arq);
int counter (FILE *arq);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) { 
    FILE *arq;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Erro de sintaxe: %s NOME_ARQUIVO\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }   
    arq = fopen(argv[1], "r");  
    if (arq == NULL){
        printf("Erro ao abrir arquivo.\n");
    }
    else {
        resize (arq);
    }
}

void resize (FILE * arq){
    aluno* std;
    int cont = counter (arq);

    std = (aluno *) malloc(cont * sizeof(*std));    
    fill (std, arq);
}

void fill (aluno* std, FILE * arq){
    char nome[15];
    int i = 0;
    float nota1, nota2;

    fseek (arq , 0 , SEEK_SET); 
    while ((fscanf (arq, "%s %f %f", nome, &nota1, &nota2)) != EOF){
        strcpy (std[i].name, nome);
        std[i].nota1 = nota1;
        std[i].nota2 = nota2;
        std[i].media = (nota1+nota2)/2; 
        i++;
    }
    printf ("\n\n\n\nArquivo carregado!\n");    
    menu (std, arq);
}

void menu (aluno* std, FILE * arq){
    int escolha;
    do {
        printf ("\n\n -- Catalogo: -- \n\n");
        printf ("1 - Inserir dado no final \n");
        printf ("2 - Inserir dado na posicao 'N' \n");
        printf ("3 - Remover dado no final \n");
        printf ("4 - Remover dado na posicao 'N' \n");
        printf ("5 - Buscar dado\n");
        printf ("\nDigite sua escolha: ");
        scanf ("%d", &escolha);

        switch (escolha){
            case 1:
                printf ("\nEscolha: 'Inserir dado no final!'");
                break;
            case 2:
                printf ("\nEscolha: 'Inserir dado na posicao - N - !'");
                break;
            case 3:
                printf ("\nEscolha: 'Remover dado no final!'");
                break;
            case 4:
                printf ("\nEscolha: 'Inserir dado na posicao - N - !'");
                break;
            case 5:
                printf ("\nEscolha: 'Buscar dado!'");
                consulta (std, arq);
                break;
            default: 
                printf ("\nEscolha: 'Inserir dado no final'!");
                break;
        }
    } while (1);
}

void consulta (aluno* std, FILE *arq){
    int cont, i=0;
    cont = counter (arq);

    printf ("\n\n Consulta de Alunos \n\n");
    printf ("Quantidade de registros: %d\n", cont);

    while (i < cont){
        printf ("O aluno %s possui: Nota 1: %.2f, Nota 2: %.2f, Media: %.2f\n", std[i].name, std[i].nota1, std[i].nota2, std[i].media);
        i ++;
    }
}

int counter (FILE * arq){
    int contador = 0;
    char nome[15];
    float nota1, nota2;

    fseek (arq , 0 , SEEK_SET);
    while ((fscanf (arq, "%s %f %f", nome, &nota1, &nota2)) != EOF){
        contador ++;
    }   
    return contador;
}
```

O erro em questão está na função `fill`.

O arquivo é formatado da seguinte forma: `nome nota nota`.

Comment: Dica pra próxima: não poste o código inteiro, isole só o trecho de código importante pra sua pergunta. Fica mais fácil de responder e às vezes fazer isso já te dá uma ideia do que pode estar causando o problema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não vou olhar o código todo e pode ter outros erros. Não tenho como testar sem isolar, o que daria trabalho e isto você deveria ter feito antes de postar. Duas coisas precisam ser consertadas.

Primeiro você tem que alocar memória para a *string* e o ponteiro para essa *string* é que deve ser guardada na estrutura. Veja que o tipo do membro `name` é um ponteiro para `char`, então só um ponteiro pode ser colocado lá.

```
while ((fscanf (arq, "%s %f %f", nome, &nota1, &nota2)) != EOF){
    char * temp = malloc(15);
    strcpy (temp, nome);
    std[i].name = temp
    std[i].nota1 = nota1;
    std[i].nota2 = nota2;
    std[i].media = (nota1+nota2)/2; 
    i++;
}
```

Eu melhoraria isto e outras coisas que podem trazer problema e ineficiência, mas não vou mexer em nada além do problema apontado.

O outro problema é que você alocou memória para ponteiros para `aluno` quando provavelmente queria criar uma área para uma uma sequência de `aluno`.

```
std = malloc(cont * sizeof(aluno));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/StrcpyProblem.c).

Comment: Na verdade a segunda alocação está ok porque ele pegou sizeof(*std), como std é do tipo aluno*, a dereferenciação pegou o struct certo.

Comment: Concordo que se fosse `std` estaria ok, mas ele pegou `*std`.

Comment: Foi typo, quis digitar sizeof([asterisco]std) :)

Comment: Então, neste caso está alocando espaço para ponteiros e não para estruturas. Isto poderia ser feito, mas aí precisa alocar as estruturas também.

Comment: Eu acho que não, porque sizeof(\*(aluno\*)) é sizeof(aluno).

Comment: Agora entendi o que você quer dizer. Vou mexer nisso.

Answer (score 4):

Acho que ficaria ideal fazendo

```
  std[i].name = strdup(nome);
```

Simplesmente atribuir você não pode, porque "nome" não é um simples valor como um int, é um endereço para uma área de memória, só que "char nome[15]" deixa de valer assim que você sai da função fill(). De alguma forma você tem de alocar e copiar o conteúdo para uma área de memória do heap; o strdup() faz as duas coisas numa chamada só.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro da estrutura `aluno` foi declarado que `name` seira um ponteiro para um caractere. O problema e que está tentando copiar o `nome` do arquivo e colocar no ponteiro `name`, que não aceita dados do tipo caractere. Pode seguir a sugestão do @Maniero ou pode alterar a sua variável `name` dentro da estrutura `aluno` .

```
typedef struct aluno
{
    char name[30];
    float nota1, nota2, media;  
}aluno;
```